# Dart Timers On Flutter apps when suspended or paused

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using password login from Firebase Auth REST API on my Flutter app. For the tokens expire every 3600 seconds, I would like to refresh the tokens with a Timer every 50 minutes.

Do the Timers run when the app is suspended or paused? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) to run a periodic task. You can just set it to execute a task every "x" minutes, which in this case would be refreshing the tokens. Or the other option is to use Kotlin combined with Java within your project, which is not recommended since it is really time consuming to do so. I tried WorkManager and it's pretty straight forward.

```
Workmanager().initialize(
    callbackDispatcher,
);
Workmanager().registrePeriodicTask(
    "uniqueName",
    frequency: Duration(minutes: 50),
    "taskName",
)

void callbackDispatcher() {
    Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) async{
        //Code
        return Future.value(true);//Required No Matter The Task
});
}
```

Comment: Any issues with different app cycles?

Comment: @KinPu As far as I know, once you initialize/register the periodic task, it will run even if the app is not in memory. This is because WorkManager will run in a separate thread. Though I've seen people initialize the work manager by modifying the java file as seen in here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60262425/how-to-make-flutter-workmanager-plugin-and-location-plugin-work-together), I found it very hard to do so, and it introduces bugs as your codebase grows. Also, on IOS WorkManager acts differently than it does on android, sometimes it even ignores the task.